# Implementing Pool on a for loop with a lot of inputs

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing, pool

I have been trying to improve my code (with numba and multiprocessing), but I cannot quite get it, because my function has a lot of arguments.

I have already simplified it with other functions (see below)...

As each agent (a class instance) is independent of each other for these actions, I would like to replace the `for` with `Pool`.

So I would get a large function `pooling()` that I would call and pass the list of agents

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(4)
p.map(pooling, list(agents))
```

But, where do I ADD all the arguments that the pooling function will need?

As it is:

```
def check_demographics(month, my_agents, families, firms, year, mortality_men, mortality_women, fertility, state_id):

    dummy = list(my_agents)
    d = str(state_id.iloc[0])

# Place where I would like to replace the LOOP. All below would be a function 

    for agent in dummy:

        if agent.get_region_id()[:2] == d:

            # Brithday
            if month % 12 == agent.month - 1:
                agent.update_age()

            # Mortality probability 
            if agent.get_gender() == 'Male':
                prob = mortality_men[mortality_men['age'] == agent.get_age()][year].iloc[0]

            # When gender is Female
            else:
                # Extract specific agent data to calculate mortality 'Female'
                prob = mortality_women[mortality_women['age'] == agent.get_age()][year].iloc[0]

            # Give birth decision 
                age = agent.get_age()
                if 14 < age < 50:
                    pregnant(agent, fertility, year, families, my_agents)

            # Mortality procedures 
            if fixed_seed.random() < prob:
                mortal(my_agents, my_graveyard, families, agent, firms)
```

It is the most time consuming function in my programme.
And `@jit` is not helping much.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Note: the global variable or parameter ``my_graveyard`` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a lot of parameters! Consider using a class.

Well, since `Pool.map` support only one iterable argument, you need to group everything in one place. I suggest you to use the "Facade" pattern: an intermediate class used to store all required parameters and having a single method (I call it `check`) without parameter (it's a method).

```
class Facade(object):
    def __init__(self, agent, d, families, fertility, firms, month, mortality_men, mortality_women, my_agents,
                 my_graveyard, year):
        self.agent = agent
        self.d = d
        self.families = families
        self.fertility = fertility
        self.firms = firms
        self.month = month
        self.mortality_men = mortality_men
        self.mortality_women = mortality_women
        self.my_agents = my_agents
        self.my_graveyard = my_graveyard
        self.year = year

    def check(self):
        (agent, d, families, fertility, firms,
         month, mortality_men, mortality_women,
         my_agents, my_graveyard, year) = (
            self.agent, self.d, self.families, self.fertility, self.firms,
            self.month, self.mortality_men, self.mortality_women,
            self.my_agents, self.my_graveyard, self.year)
        if agent.get_region_id()[:2] == d:

            # Brithday
            if month % 12 == agent.month - 1:
                agent.update_age()

            # Mortality probability
            if agent.get_gender() == 'Male':
                prob = mortality_men[mortality_men['age'] == agent.get_age()][year].iloc[0]

            # When gender is Female
            else:
                # Extract specific agent data to calculate mortality 'Female'
                prob = mortality_women[mortality_women['age'] == agent.get_age()][year].iloc[0]

                # Give birth decision
                age = agent.get_age()
                if 14 < age < 50:
                    pregnant(agent, fertility, year, families, my_agents)

            # Mortality procedures
            if fixed_seed.random() < prob:
                mortal(my_agents, my_graveyard, families, agent, firms)
```

*Remark: my refactoring is really ugly, but I wanted to keep variable names unchanged for clarity.*

Then your loop can be something like that:

```
def check_demographics(month, my_agents, families, firms,
                       year, mortality_men, mortality_women,
                       fertility, state_id, my_graveyard):
    d = str(state_id.iloc[0])
    pool = Pool(4)
    facades = [Facade(agent, d, families, fertility, firms,
                      month, mortality_men, mortality_women,
                      my_agents, my_graveyard, year)
               for agent in my_agents]
    pool.map(Facade.check, facades)
```

You said that each agent is independent of each other but, after analysing the loop, I see that you need the complete list of agents (the `my_agents` parameters). It's obvious with the `Facade` class. So your agent list must not change and the internal state of each agent must be frozen during looping.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. But you are right the list `my_agents` changes. That is why I created a new `list(agents)`through which I iterate. Will that work in this case?

Comment: At least apply ``map`` on the copy of agents: ``list(agents)``. Why does the list change?

Comment: I did. I also got this error `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function Facade.check at 0x00000000084C0840>: attribute lookup check on demographics failed` The list changes because I have to remove an agent when he/she dies. And in your example, I don't have the agent until I have initiated the `for loop`

Comment: Instead of removing the "dead" agents, build another list to store "alive" agents. Use the ``check`` method return value: return the agent if "alive" or ``None`` if "dead".

Comment: Still the error. Everything must be pickable. My inputs include pandas DataFrames, lists of instances, strings and int